# Spring boot Flyway Jooq Code gen maven plugin order

Tags: spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin, jooq, flyway

How can I enforce flyway:migrate to be executed always before jooq:generate-sources?
I am using maven wrapper with spring boot.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <generator>
                    <database>
                        <name>org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
                        <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
                    </database>
                    <target>
                        <packageName>bg.kotz.db</packageName>
                        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                    </target>
                </generator>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you generate code in `src/main/java`, all things start to break in Maven. Better keep it to the default of generating to `target/...`, or, if you want to check in generated sources, create separate Maven projects for Flyway migration and jOOQ code generation

Answer (score 1):

You also have to add `executions` block to `flyway-maven-plugin` section for made flyway execute migrations under `generate-sources` step:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
  <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>6.3.3</version>
  <executions>
     <execution>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>migrate</goal>
        </goals>
     </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
  <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
  <version>3.13.1</version>
  <executions>
     <execution>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
     </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <generator>
       <database>
          <name>org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
          <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
        </database>
        <target>
          <packageName>bg.kotz.db</packageName>
          <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        </target>
      </generator>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: it worked, kind of. when I type spring-boot:run it:
1. migrates the schema
2. generated classes with jooq,
3. compiles and starts

but on step 3 it tries to migrate again and fails with this error:
"Message    : ERROR: relation "foo" already exists"
I don't know why, flyway_schema_history is present and there is a record.

Comment: What flyway version do you use in your app?